# Mover todos os arquivos com a extensão .prj para uma pasta

Tags: delphi, recursão, diretório

Gostaria de saber se é possível a seguinte situação:

Existe varias pastas uma dentro da outra... e dentro delas existem arquivos com a extensão `.prj`.

É possível ler todas as pastas, ir encontrando os arquivos `.prj`, e ir colando em uma pasta de resultado?

Comment: Qual a versão do Delphi? Você quer copiar os arquivos ou movê-los?

Comment: Delhpi xe-8, move-los seria o ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em versões mais recentes do Delphi, existe uma função que faz isso: [`IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles), para usá-la, adicione `IOUtils` em `Uses`.

Use assim:

```
Uses
  IOUtils;
//...

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  EXTENSAO = '*.prj';
var
  DynArray: TStringDynArray;
  Diretorio, DiretorioBackup, DiretorioResultado: string;
  Arquivo, NomeArquivo: string;
  TotalArquivos, Sucessos, Erros: Integer;
begin
  // Cria um diretório "backup" na pasta selecionada
  DiretorioBackup := IncludeTrailingBackslash('Backup');
  // Cria o diretório para onde será movido os arquivos
  DiretorioResultado := IncludeTrailingBackslash('Resultado');

  try
    // Para selecionar somente diretórios!
    FileOpenDialog1.Options := [fdoPickFolders];
    if FileOpenDialog1.Execute = False then exit;

    // Atenção! Se for pegar o diretório de um arquivo use o ExtractFileDir/ExtractFilePath
    Diretorio := IncludeTrailingBackslash(FileOpenDialog1.FileName);

    // Se o diretório de backup não existir, um é criado
    if not DirectoryExists(Diretorio + DiretorioBackup) then
      CreateDir(Diretorio + DiretorioBackup);

    // Se o diretório não existir, cria-se um
    if not DirectoryExists(Diretorio + DiretorioResultado) then
      CreateDir(Diretorio + DiretorioResultado);

    // Pega os arquivos com a extensão definida constante EXTENSAO, procura em todos
    // diretórios e subdiretórios
    DynArray := TDirectory.GetFiles(Diretorio, EXTENSAO, TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);

    for Arquivo in DynArray do
    begin
      Inc(TotalArquivos);
      // Extrai o nome do arquivo
      NomeArquivo := ExtractFileName(Arquivo);

      // Faz a cópia dos arquivos para o diretório de backup
      // Se o backup existir, ele é substituído, os arquivos terão extensão ".ZZZ"
      CopyFile(pchar(Arquivo), pchar(Diretorio + DiretorioBackup + NomeArquivo + '.ZZZ'), false);

      // Move os arquivos para o diretório "resultado"
      if MoveFile(pchar(Arquivo), pchar(Diretorio + DiretorioResultado + NomeArquivo)) then
        Inc(Sucessos)
      else
        Inc(Erros);
    end;

    MessageBox(0,
             pchar(Format('Total: %d' + sLineBreak + 'Arquivos movidos: %d Erros: %d',
               [TotalArquivos, Sucessos, Erros])),
               'Backup',
               MB_ICONINFORMATION);

  finally
  end;
end;
```

### Alternativa

Uma outra alternativa é usar as funções [`Findfirst`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=findfirst) e [`FindNext`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FindNext) de forma recursiva para procurar os arquivos:

```
procedure ListarArquivos(Dir: string; const Ext: string; const Lista: TStringList);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  Dir := IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir);

  if FindFirst(Dir + '*.*', faAnyFile or faDirectory, SR) = 0 then
  try
    repeat
      if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0) and (Pos(Ext, SR.Name) > 0)  then
        lista.Add(dir + SR.Name)

      else if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') then
        ListarArquivos(Dir + SR.Name, Ext, Lista);
    until FindNext(Sr) <> 0;

  finally
    FindClose(SR);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;
```

Para usar faça:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  EXTENSAO = '.prj'; // Sem o coringa!
var
  ListaArquivos: TStringList;
  Diretorio, DiretorioBackup, DiretorioResultado: string;
  Arquivo, NomeArquivo: string;
  TotalArquivos, Sucessos, Erros: Integer;
begin
  // Cria um diretório "backup" na pasta selecionada
  DiretorioBackup := IncludeTrailingBackslash('Backup');
  // Cria o diretório para onde será movido os arquivos
  DiretorioResultado := IncludeTrailingBackslash('Resultado');

  try
    ListaArquivos := TStringList.Create;

    // Para selecionar somente diretórios!
    FileOpenDialog1.Options := [fdoPickFolders];
    if FileOpenDialog1.Execute = False then exit;

    // Atenção! Se for pegar o diretório de um arquivo use o ExtractFileDir/ExtractFilePath
    Diretorio := IncludeTrailingBackslash(FileOpenDialog1.FileName);

    // Se o diretório de backup não existir, um é criado
    if not DirectoryExists(Diretorio + DiretorioBackup) then
      CreateDir(Diretorio + DiretorioBackup);

    // Se o diretório não existir, cria-se um
    if not DirectoryExists(Diretorio + DiretorioResultado) then
      CreateDir(Diretorio + DiretorioResultado);

    // Pega os arquivos com a extensão definida constante EXTENSAO, procura em todos
    // diretórios e subdiretórios
    ListarArquivos(Diretorio, EXTENSAO, ListaArquivos);

    for Arquivo in ListaArquivos do
    begin
      Inc(TotalArquivos);
      // Extrai o nome do arquivo
      NomeArquivo := ExtractFileName(Arquivo);

      // Faz a cópia dos arquivos para o diretório de backup
      // Se o backup existir, ele é substituído, os arquivos terão extensão ".ZZZ"
      CopyFile(pchar(Arquivo), pchar(Diretorio + DiretorioBackup + NomeArquivo + '.ZZZ'), false);

      // Move os arquivos para o diretório "resultado"
      if MoveFile(pchar(Arquivo), pchar(Diretorio + DiretorioResultado + NomeArquivo)) then
        Inc(Sucessos)
      else
        Inc(Erros);
    end;

    MessageBox(0,
               pchar(Format('Total: %d' + sLineBreak + 'Arquivos movidos: %d Erros: %d',
               [TotalArquivos, Sucessos, Erros])),
               'Backup',
               MB_ICONINFORMATION);

  finally
    ListaArquivos.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Nota**: Ambos os exemplos criam dois diretórios, um para guardar cópias de segurança dos arquivos, esses terão a extensão `.zzz`, o segundo diretório é para onde serão movidos os arquivos `.prj`.

Comment: Alterei na `procedure ListarArquivos` de `Pos(Ext, SR.Name) > 0` `Pos(LowerCase(Ext), LowerCase(SR.Name)) > 0` para considerar as extensões minusculas ou maiúsculas :) Obrigado.